# How to random the choices in php

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am creating a random generated quiz with 10 questions. In generating the random question is fine, but I want to display also the choices in random, same with the questions.

This is my code that I am currently working with:

```
<?php
  generate();
  function generate(){
    include('connection.php');
    mysql_select_db('exam');
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questionaires
                         INNER JOIN choices ON questionaires.q_id=choices.q_id
                         WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((10/COUNT(*))*10) FROM questionaires)
                         ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
    $c=0;
    echo "<table border='3' align='center' bordercolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <tr>
              <th>Number:</th>
              <th>Question</th>
            </tr>
          ";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $c++;
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $c . "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['question'] . "<br>";
      echo "<input type='radio' name='ans'>".$row['choice_a']."</input><br>";
      echo "<input type='radio' name='ans'>".$row['choice_b']."</input><br>";
      echo "<input type='radio' name='ans'>".$row['choice_c']."</input><br>";
      echo "<input type='radio' name='ans'>".$row['choice_d']."</input><br>";
      echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    //}
   //}
    }
    echo "</table>";
  }
?>
```

Little help will highly appreciated.

Comment: You could add all the questions and/or answers in an array and use the `array_shuffle` method to shuffle the array.

Comment: even im using different tables for questions and choices, also different table for the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change script to this:

```
echo "<td>";
echo $row['question'] . "<br>";

$ans=array($row['choice_a'],$row['choice_b'],$row['choice_c'],$row['choice_d']);
shuffle($ans);

foreach ($ans as $choice) {
    echo "<input type='radio' name='ans'>".$choice."</input><br>";
} unset($choice);

echo "</td>";
```